# autocomplete on client side using richfaces

Tags: html, autocomplete, richfaces

I have a table of customers and i'm trying to use autocomplete when searching it.  the problem is that the autocomplete search suggestions box takes about 2-3 seconds to show even though there are only about 3000 customers.
I thought about creating a var that would contain all customers which would be created when the page loads, and when someone searches for a customer, the search would take place only on the client side.
I have no idea how to do that in RichFaces.  please help.

what I have so far (slow search from server) - customerSuggestBox.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"    
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"      
      xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">

<ui:composition>

    <ui:define name="forItem">customerText</ui:define>
<rich:suggestionbox for="${forItem}" tokens=",[" 
                suggestionAction="#{customerUtilAction.getCustomersByName}" var="cus"
                selfRendered="true"
                ignoreDupResponses="true"
                fetchValue="#{cus.businessUnit.name}" 
                first="0"
                minChars="2"
                shadowOpacity="5"
                border="1" width="400"
                height="250" 
                onselect="setCaretToEnd(event);"
                reRender="#{reRender}"
                shadowDepth="1"
                cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1"             nothingLabel="No customers found" columnClasses="center">

                 <h:column>

                <h:outputText value="#{cus.businessUnit.name}" />                                
                 </h:column>
                   <h:column>

                    <h:outputText value="#{messages[cus.businessRelationship.name()]}" />             
                 </h:column>
                  <ui:insert name="reRender"></ui:insert>               

                </rich:suggestionbox>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

forgot to say:
another xhtml includes this one and sends it parameter "forItem"

```
                                            <ui:include src="customerSuggestBox.xhtml">

                                            <ui:param 
                                                name="forItem"
                                                value="customerText" />
                                        </ui:include>
```

Comment: the 2-3 sec delay can be everything.. is the DB query efficient? is the business logic efficient? (I have a slow DB layer, solved it with a "loading" gif to show the user there is something happening)

Comment: yes, perhaps I should have mentioned, the query is efficient, everything is fine with the DB.  I thought about a "loading" gif but I prefer to change the autocomplete if possible.